# Enemies follows the player in middle

Tags: python, pygame

The enemies spawn above the screen and try to follow the player in the middle of the screen but when it gets near the player the game crashes with a error instead of a game over.

How do I pass the player coordinates in enemies class update() method instead of 600,325 i.e. height, width respectively of the window.

I want to make enemies to follow the player and spawn the enemies around random place outside the player rather from only above the screen, also how to increase the enemies as score increases.

The error I get is:

```
dirvect.normalize()
ValueError: Can't normalize Vector of length Zero
```

The below code is of class enemy:

```
class Mob(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.image.load('enemy.png').convert_alpha()
        self.image = pg.transform.smoothscale(pg.image.load('enemy.png'), (33, 33))
        self.image_orig = self.image.copy()
        self.radius = int(29 * .80 / 2)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(width - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speed = 4
        self.rot = 0
        self.rot_speed = 5
        self.last_update = pg.time.get_ticks()

    def rotate(self):
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > 50:
            self.last_update = now
            self.rot = (self.rot + self.rot_speed) % 360
            new_image = pg.transform.rotozoom(self.image_orig, self.rot, 1)
            old_center = self.rect.center
            self.image = new_image
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = old_center

    def update(self):
        self.rotate()
        dirvect = pg.math.Vector2(600 - self.rect.x,
                                  325 - self.rect.y)
        dirvect.normalize()
    # Move along this normalized vector towards the player at current speed.
        dirvect.scale_to_length(self.speed)
        self.rect.move_ip(dirvect)
        if self.rect.top > height + 10 or self.rect.left < -25 or self.rect.right > width + 20:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(width - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
            self.speed = random.randrange(1, 4)
```

The below is for adding enemies:

```
    for i in range(5):
        m = Mob()
        all_sprites.add(m)
        mobs.add(m)
 score = 0
```

If this helps the code of player class:

```
class Rotator(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen_rect):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.screen_rect = screen_rect
        self.master_image = pg.image.load('spaceship.png').convert_alpha()
        self.master_image = pg.transform.smoothscale(pg.image.load('spaceship.png'), (33, 33))
        self.radius = 12
        self.image = self.master_image.copy()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=[width / 2, height / 2])
        self.delay = 10
        self.timer = 0.0
        self.angle = 0
        self.distance = 0
        self.angle_offset = 0

    def get_angle(self):
        mouse = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        offset = (self.rect.centerx - mouse[0], self.rect.centery - mouse[1])
        self.angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(*offset)) - self.angle_offset
        old_center = self.rect.center
        self.image = pg.transform.rotozoom(self.master_image, self.angle, 1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=old_center)
        self.distance = math.sqrt((offset[0] * offset[0]) + (offset[1] * offset[1]))

    def update(self):
        self.get_angle()
        self.display = 'angle:{:.2f} distance:{:.2f}'.format(self.angle, self.distance)
        self.dx = 1
        self.dy = 1
        self.rect.clamp_ip(self.screen_rect)

    def draw(self, surf):
        surf.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def shoot(self, mousepos):
        dx = mousepos[0] - self.rect.centerx
        dy = mousepos[1] - self.rect.centery
        if abs(dx) > 0 or abs(dy) > 0:
            bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery, dx, dy)
            all_sprites.add(bullet)
            bullets.add(bullet)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is cause, because the length of `dirvect` is zero. Note, the length of a [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) is 1 and a unit vector is calculated by dividing the vector by its length.

Check the length of the vector before calculating the unit vector. Use [`length_squared()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.length_squared) to get the squared [Euclidean length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) of the vector, this is faster then getting the length by [`lenght()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.length), because the expensive square root operation is omitted:

```py
if vectdirvect.length_squared() > 0:
    vectdirvect = vectdirvect.normalize()
```

Further note, that [`normalize()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.normalize) calculates the unit vector, but it doesn't store the result to "itself", it returns the result by the return value.

---

A similar issue happens when you use [`scale_to_length()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.scale_to_length), because `scale_to_length()` has to calculate the unit vector first, before it can scale the vector to a given length:

```py
if dirvect.length_squared() > 0:
    dirvect.scale_to_length(self.speed)
```

Comment: With an error: dirvect.scale_to_length(self.speed)
ValueError: Cannot scale a vector with zero length

Comment: @AkhilAnandSirra Same issue, see the answer (2nd part).

Comment: How do I get the live player coordinates instead of passing 600,325 in dirvect = pg.math.Vector2(600 - self.rect.x, 325 - self.rect.y)

Comment: Also spawn enemies randomly around the screen instead from only above the screen